# Parsing Zip file in TS. Despite await, returned result appears empty while result within function is not

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, jszip

I'm writing some code to parse all CSV files stored inside a Zip folder.
I'm using JSZip for this. I'm looping over all files of a `dataset` and converting each file into an `entry`. I'm concatenating the result in an array called `entries`.

This is what happens to the `entries` array when:

1. I log it to console from within the loop - Prints file correctly.
2. I log it to console from the same function right outside the loop without setTimeout - Prints empty array
3. I log it to console from the same function right outside the loop WITH setTimeout - Prints file correctly.

Now I returned `entries` from this function, I tried returning it from the:

1. setTimeout - returns undefined
2. Right outside setTimeout - returns empty array

Here is the code:

```
private async parseAllFiles (dataset: JSZip, id: string): Promise<string[]> {
    let entries: string[] = [];

    await dataset.forEach(  async (fileName) => {
        const fileContent = await dataset.file(fileName).async("text");  // async func provided by JSZip
        const parsedEntries = await this.parseCsv(fileContent, courseCode); // another async function
    });
    console.log('Entries are: \n');
    console.log(entries);                  // Prints empty array

    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log("Entries are: ");
        console.log(entries);          // prints perfectly
        return Promise.resolve(entries); // returns undefined
    }, 1500);
    // return Promise.resolve(entries);   // returns empty array
}
```

I'm pretty sure `entries` is getting returned too early, but how do I fix that, preferably without using a manual setTimeout ?

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` is a void returning function, and thus isn't awaitable.

What you could do is create an array of Promises:

```
const promises: Promise[] = [];
```

Then add to the array within your `forEach`:

```
dataset.forEach(fileName => {
    promises.push(async () => {
        const fileContent = await dataset.file(fileName).async("text");
        const parsedEntries = await this.parseCsv(fileContent, courseCode);
        return parsedEntries;
    });
});
```

Then wait for them all to complete:

```
const entries: string[] = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat();
```

`Promise.all` returns a new `Promise`, which resolves to an array of the provided `Promise` results.

These can be flattened into a single array using `Array.flat()`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, awaiting for all these promises to fulfil like this returns an array of functions.

Comment: You haven't made clear what `entries` should be. Should each `parsedEntries` be added to `entries`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I'm trying to achieve here. I had this line in my code:
 entries = entries.concat(parsedEntries);
I didn't realise it wasn't in the code I posted. Very sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I tried to use a loop to call all the functions in the returned array but that brings me back to the same problem - awaiting for a forEach. I've added the line of code that concatenates parsedEntries to entries.

Comment: Thanks again but it says: "Property 'flat' does not exist on type any[]" seems like my version of node doesn't have the function flat itself. I'll look into that and comment back here.

Comment: Looks like it has support from v11. For older versions you could `.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);`